# Data in cache hot swap

Tags: java, caching, hotswap

I have some data selected from database and cached in memory.I use them quite frequently.But sometimes I need to update this data,and I don't want to stop the server.Is there any available solutions for this?

Comment: Have you checked if you can refresh the data in your cache?

Comment: I am worried about there might be some read-write concurrent issues.

Comment: If you're manually caching the data, then you **should not** do it again and use a third party library that already handles this scenario like ehcache or infinispan.

Comment: Sometimes I don't know which element of cache need to be updated.I need to reload all of it from database,but I can't shutdown the service?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DB cache (Try using Ehcache, it supports JDBC caching).

Or provide some external interface that you can send a message to, to tell you app to update from the DB.

Comment: Sometimes I don't know which element of cache need to be updated.I need to reload all of it from database,but I can't shutdown the service?

Comment: I mean if I can make 2 copies of it,and hot swap the cache totally.Is there any available third party library could do this?

Comment: did you look up `Ehcache` as mentioned in my answer?